# Maple leaf stains on new interlocking brick patio

Tags: tile

Our brand new natural stone interlocking pavers has been  stained by our maple leaves.  The stain is very dark and deep. Can anyone provide guidance in how to remove these stains?

Comment: Is the patio colored or raw concrete type bricks a photo would be helpful , some treatments cannot be done on colored pavers without risk of washing out the colors.

Comment: The pavers have tinges of grey and are of natural stone.  I was told to power wash and then use gst florescence. Do you have any additional comments? Thank you.

Comment: I might try a Tri sodium phosphate type of cleaner, my standard is muriatic acid but that may change the color that is why I asked if they had color, TSP may take the stain out . If that is not strong enough a 15% muriatic acid and water solution would definitely take any Tannin out but may affect the color. I would experiment in a area that is not in view. But would probably try the TSP first as it won’t etch and may remove the stain.